# How To Change Flot Legend Structure

Tags: flot

I need the legend table to have multiple columns instead of one. And I want to add headers to it.

What is the best way to do that?
(I know it's not common, But in this case, each data series has it's own record of information.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend):

The `legend` property of the options has a number of columns property (`noColumns`). In addition you can specify your own `container` and/or a `labelFormatter` function to customize the legend (for example use an empty `<table>` as container and generate `<tr>`/`<td>` elements in the formatter function).

If that is not enough you could let *flot* build the default legend and then rearrange and customize it afterwards.